# Adding a new row into a table while clicking a button, each table row contains reactive form controls

Tags: angular

How can I dynamically add a row while clicking a button in Angular 9, each row contains reactive form fields maded with Angular Material.
The GUI looks like this: 
[GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNIJO.png)

What I want to do is add a new row with the same fields as the first row, and manage these rows in FormGroup array.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried yet, but I have some notes that may help you.
It's meant to allow the user to add multiple addresses (notes based on a tutorial from [@DeborahK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1647604/deborahk))

```
buildAddress(): FormGroup {
 return this.fb.group({
   addressType: 'home',
   street1: '',
   street2: '',
   city: '',
   state: '',
   zip: ''
  });
}
this.customerForm= this.fb.group({
...
addresses: this.fb.array([this.buildAddress()])
});


Creating a FormArray
this.myArray= newFormArray([...]);
or
this.myArray= this.fb.array([...]);

Looping
<div formArrayName="addresses"
 *ngFor="let address of addresses.controls; let i=index">
<div [formGroupName]="i">

Duplicate the Input Elements
get addresses(): FormArray {
  return this.customerForm.get('addresses') as FormArray;
}
addAddress(): void {
 this.addresses.push(this.buildAddress());
}
<button class="btnbtn-primary" type="button" (click)="addAddress()"> Add Another Address </button>
```